# How to print index and value in array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to print text with an index and its value. This is the code

```
test_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
for index, value in enumerate(test_list):
   print("S1_vec('index')<=", value)
```

Getting output

```
S1_vec('index')<= 1
S1_vec('index')<= 4
S1_vec('index')<= 5
S1_vec('index')<= 6
S1_vec('index')<= 7
```

But I want my output to print an index value

```
S1_vec('0')<= 1
S1_vec('1')<= 4
S1_vec('2')<= 5
S1_vec('3')<= 6
S1_vec('4')<= 7
```

Can anyone please help me to correct this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a sufficiently recent Python, f-strings are probably easiest:

```
print(f"S1_vec('{index}') <= {value}")
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you are passing `index` as literal string which is incorrect.

Use `f-strings` for python3.6+:

```
test_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
for index, value in enumerate(test_list):
   print(f"S1_vec('{index}')<= {value}")
```

or `format()` for lower versions:

```
test_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
for index, value in enumerate(test_list):
   print("S1_vec('{}')<= {}".format(index, value))
```